# Finding a diagonal matrix $B$ and a unitary matrix $C$ that satisfy $B=C^{-1}AC$.

Tags: linear-algebra, diagonalization, unitary-matrices

> The matrix $A$ is given as $$A=\frac{1}{9} \begin{bmatrix} 4+3i & 4i & -6-2i \\ -4i & 4-3i & -2-6i \\ 6+2i & -2-6i & 1 \end{bmatrix}$$
>   Find a diagonal matrix $B$ and a unitary matrix $C$ that satisfy $B=C^{-1}AC$.

Could anyone help me deal with this + explain the algorithm to find $B$ and $C$ in a little bit more detailed way? I didn't understand everything well by reading the book.

I've already found the eigenvalues $\lambda_1=1, \ \ \lambda_2=i, \ \ \lambda_3=-i$ and the eigenvectors $v_1=(-2i \ \  -2  \ \ 1)^T, \ \  v_2=(i \ \ -1/2 \ \ 1)^T, \ \  v_3=(-i/2 \ \ 1 \ \ 1)^T$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now, you divide each of those vectors by its norm, thereby getting$$w_1=\frac13(-2i\ \ -2\ \ 1)^T,\ w_2=\frac13(2i\ \ -1\ \ 2)^T\text{, and }w_3=\frac13(-i\ \ 2\ \ 2)^T.$$And then you take$$C=\frac13\begin{bmatrix}-2i&2i&-i\\-2&-1&2\\1&2&2\end{bmatrix},$$whose columns are the vectors $w_1$, $w_2$, and $w_3$. And you're done.

Comment: By finding norm you mean magnitude?

Comment: No. I mean norm.

Comment: http://mathonline.wikidot.com/the-norm-of-a-vector is it the same thing?

Comment: I don't know, since I don't know what is the magnitude of a vector. But the norm of $v=(z_1,z_2,z_3)$ is$$\sqrt{|z_1|^2+|z_2|^2+|z_3|^3}.$$

Comment: Ok, then the norm of $v_1$ is equal to $1$ , then $w_1$ should be equal to $v_1$. How did you get the coefficien $1/3$?

Comment: From the fact that $\|v_1\|=\sqrt{4+4+1}=3$.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I didn't notice the modules. Thanks. And please could give any links so that I could learn about proving this algorithm?

Answer (score 1):

You already have the answer. Since you know the eigenvalues are $1,i,-i$, then a diagonal matrix $B$ is
$$
            \left[\begin{array}{ccc}1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & i & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & -i\end{array}\right]
$$

Comment: Sorry, I forgot about asking for $C$ too. Now edited.

Comment: @VIVID : The matrix $C$ to go with my $B$ is the matrix with the unit eigenvectors in the rows of $C$ with the top row being the eigenvector with eigenvalue $1$, the second row being the eigenvector with eigenvalue $i$ and the third row being the eigenvector with eigenvalue $-i$. Then $U=C^{T}BC$

Comment: Ok, got you, thanks!